# How ByVal works for Objects in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, byval

My question is regarding the concept for working of ByVal in vb.net.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub ManipulateDetails()
Dim tObject1 as New customdatatype

tObject1.sName = "Stack"
tObject1.sLastName = "Over"

GetManipulateDetails(tObject1)

End Sub


Private Function GetManipulateDetails(ByVal tObject1 as customdatatype)

tObject1.sName = "Stack-Over-Flow"
tObject1.sLastName = "Flow-Over-Stack"
Return tObject1

End Function
```

In the above code snippet I am sending tObject1 as ByVal in the GetManipulateDetails function, when the values are changed in this subroutine the object which is returned back, manipulates the actual object which was passed.
i.e. if I quickwatch the object in the method ManipulateDetails I can see the manipulated details.
Also if I am returning the object in the subroutine function the value is getting reflected in the original object which was passed.

as the value is getting changed even without returning the object from the function GetManipulateDetails, I am confused whether this is happening because of ByRef?? or there is some other mechanism which is making this work.

Answer (score 3):

It may be clearer if we use different names:

```
Private Sub ManipulateDetails()
Dim tObject1 as New customdatatype

tObject1.sName = "Stack"
tObject1.sLastName = "Over"

GetManipulateDetails(tObject1)

End Sub


Private Function GetManipulateDetails(ByVal tother as customdatatype) as customdatatype

tother.sName = "Stack-Over-Flow"
tother.sLastName = "Flow-Over-Stack"
Return tother

End Function
```

Before you call `GetManipulateDetails`, `tObject1` is a *reference* to an object of type `customdatatype`. When you call `GetManipulateDetails`, `tother` gets a copy of `tObject1`. Importantly, what this means is that now, `tObject1` and `tother` are both *references* to the same object. What was copied was the *reference*, not the object. Within `GetManipulateDetails`, it can use its *copy* of the reference to access the object and make changes to it.

`ByVal` parameters are always copied - but parameters are either value types or references. They're never reference types (aka objects) themselves.

Comment: So... If we change the code above to tObject1 = GetManipulatedDetails(tObject1) the returned values will be tObject1.sName = "Stack-Over-Flow" and tObject1.sLastName = "Flow-Over-Stack"

Comment: @Mych - we don't have to change the code for that to be true because there's only one `customdatatype` object, it's a reference type, and tObject1` has always been holding a reference to it.

Comment: Ah... understood... this will help me with similar issue.